# How do I modify my development environment to create a network drive alias?

Tags: windows, alias

Disclaimers: This question is straddling a weird boundary between coding and SuperUser territory. I'm not even sure what terminology to use for half of what I'm asking so bear with me...

I'm working on a check in/out type of function for a remote client where they want to move some files back and forth between users' local machines and a central network location. They want the network location to be configurable. During the development for the past few weeks we've had the configured directory set to something simple like "C:\Storage" for initial testing purposes, and I created a Storage directory on the C: drive of my dev environment.

Today I got the network configuration they want to start using. I was hoping they'd use a mapped network drive so I could just map the same letter to my local drive and have my dev environment continue to work using their new configuration file. Unfortunately, the path they want to use points directly to some machine on their internal network using "\machinename\dir\dir\dir...".

Is there some way to set up my development environment such that when I encounter their network path using `DirectoryInfo` or whatever it will resolve to a local directory? If it was a mapped network drive I could use `subst` at the command prompt to point their letter at a directory on my local drive, but with this full path I don't know how to do something similar or if it's possible.

Comment: What is the exact problem? You should be able to access network paths without issue in code... is the problem you need to set it up on your local box to look like a network path for dev purposes?

Comment: Yes, that's the exact problem. I'm not sure whether it's better to think of it as doing something special to a local folder so it has an address that looks like a network location or creating a special network location path that points at a local folder. Either way, given a specific path of the format "\\name\dir\dir" I need it to resolve on my local box to some local folder.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand your problem a little better:

If you want to access your local computer using a UNC path, you'll need to setup a share, which it sounds like you already have. Then you can access it via:

```
\\localhost\c$\dir\dir
```

Hopefully that is good enough to get your work done on the dev side.

Comment: That's not quite where I was going. I don't want to access a folder using any old UNC path, I need to make my machine think that the client's specific UNC path exists and points at some local directory. I know the specific path in their configuration is "\\rnodfs\dat1\cse\storage". I want my local box to resolve that specific path to some local directory so I can test the code that moves the files back and forth using their configuration file. The reason for this is that we've put their config file in our deployment folder for building the installer and now it gets put on my dev box too.

Comment: If this can't be done it's not the end of the world, I can add a "dev" config file to our vault and deploy it over their version when I do a dev-specific deployment, but then I have to keep the two config file versions in sync and if there's a simple way to spoof their UNC path that seems much less error prone...